# Trying to open an image in Google Maps info window adapter

Tags: java, android, android-glide

Whenever I click a marker, all of the views are inflated, but the image is just stuck on the placeholder and the image doesn't load. If I click a second time then the image is loaded properly. Here is my adapter code:

```
public class CustomWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
CustomWindowAdapter.Callback mCallback;
Context context;
interface Callback {
    Attraction getDictionary(String key);
}
LayoutInflater mInflater;
CustomWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater i, CustomWindowAdapter.Callback callback) {mInflater = i;
    mCallback = callback;}
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
    String name = marker.getTitle();
    Attraction attraction = mCallback.getDictionary(name);
    String imageUrl = attraction.getImage().getUrl();

    View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
    context = v.getContext();
    // Populate fields
    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvInfoName);
    title.setText(name);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivInfo);

    TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvInfoDescription);
    description.setText(marker.getSnippet());

    ImageView imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.ivInfo);
    if(imageUrl != null)
    Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl)
            .apply(RequestOptions
                    .placeholderOf(R.color.placeholderColor)
                    .circleCrop())
            .into(imageView);
    // Return info window contents
    return v;
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    return null;
}
```

}

The dictionary is simply how I keep the information of each location to be accessed later on.

Comment: do not implement method `getInfoContents()`, or at least call `super.getInfoContents(marker);`

Comment: When I try to not implement getInfoContents(), there is an error saying that I need to implement required methods